# Solve the equation $x^3 + 117y^3 = 5$ over the integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Solve the equation $x^3 + 117y^3 = 5$ over the integers.

I have tried solving this. It is clear that one of $x$ or $y$ must be negative. $117$ seemed a strange number. So I found out that $117 = 125 - 8 = 5^3 - 2^3$. I don't know if this is useful but still I'm adding it. So the equation becomes:

$$x^3 + (5y)^3 - (2y)^3 = 5$$

I don't know how to proceed further. I need some hints. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take $\pmod{3^2}$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How did you know we had to take a $\pmod 9$?

Comment: @Dhrub,  As the power of $x,y$ are $3$

Comment: @Dhruv By [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) $(3k\pm 1)^3\equiv \pm 1\pmod 9$. Similarly, $(pk+a)^p\equiv a^p\pmod{p^2}$ for any prime $p$, which gives that there are at most $p$ $p$'th powers mod $p^2$ (in this case, there are only $3$ $3$'th powers mod $3^2$, so using mod $3^2$ makes sense).

Comment: Using mod $7$ would also make sense, because $x^3\equiv \{0,\pm 1\}\pmod{7}$, but unfortunately it doesn't solve it. By [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $x^6\equiv \{0,1\}\pmod{7}$, so $x^3\equiv \{0,\pm 1\}\pmod{7}$. More generally, $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \{0,\pm 1\}\pmod{p}$ for any odd prime $p$ (see [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) for a stronger result, namely $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\pmod{p}$ for any odd prime $p$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$x^3 \equiv 0,1,8 (\bmod 9)$$
$$117y^3 \equiv 0 (\bmod 9)$$
$$5 \equiv 5 (\bmod 9)$$

Comment: Admittedly, that is nearly the full proof, but +1.

Comment: Haha, and here I was asking Sage to calculate the class group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{-117})$.  +1

Comment: @Roman83 How did you know we had to take a $\pmod 9$?

Comment: @Dhruv: I saw that $9|117$ and  remembered that $x^3 \equiv 0,1,8 (\bmod 9) $

Comment: @Roman83 Great thinking. Thanks.

Comment: To prove that $x^3\equiv \{0,\pm 1\}\pmod{9}$, notice that by Binomial Theorem it's easy to see that $(3k\pm 1)^3\equiv \pm 1\pmod{9}$.